# Count without 2nd subquery in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, subquery

I am trying to attain the count of users that ordered at least 1 product on multiple days.

**Transactions Table**

```
usr_id|transt_id|product_id|spend| transaction_date

4       8           32      40      2020-05-08 17:54:59
4       7           31      20      2020-05-01 17:54:59
4       7           31      40      2020-05-01 17:54:59
4       6           20      30      2020-05-02 17:54:59
4       6           19      20      2020-05-02 17:54:59
4       6           18      10      2020-05-02 17:54:59
3       5           17      20      2020-05-04 17:54:59
3       5           16      10      2020-05-04 17:54:59
2       3           14      30      2020-05-04 18:54:59
2       3           13      50      2020-05-04 18:54:59
1       2           12      30      2020-05-05 20:54:59
1       2           12      40      2020-05-05 20:54:59
1       2           12      40      2020-05-04 20:54:59
1       1           11      20      2020-05-05 21:54:59
1       1           10      40      2020-05-05 21:54:59
3       4           10      60      2020-05-06 17:54:59
```

Through my code I have been able to reach to a point where the output is:

```
select user_id, count(*)
from (
select user_id, date(transaction_date)
from transactions
group by user_id, date(transaction_date)) as abc
group by user_id
having count(user_id)>1;
```

```
user_id | count
1           2
3           2
4           3
```

**I want to write a code without writing another subquery to get the count of users having count(*)>1;
The output should be: 3.

In other words, I don't want the following code; I want to write one less subquery or a completely new query**

```
select count(*)
from (
select user_id, count(*)
from (
select user_id, date(transaction_date)
from transactions
group by user_id, date(transaction_date)) as abc
group by user_id
having count(user_id)>1) as bcd;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you already have could be written without a subquery:

```
select user_id, count(distinct date(transaction_date)) count
from transactions
group by user_id
having count(distinct date(transaction_date))>1;
```

So what you need now can be written with only 1 subquery:

```
select count(*) count
from (
  select user_id
  from transactions
  group by user_id
  having count(distinct date(transaction_date))>1
) t
```

You can get the same result with `EXISTS`:

```
select count(distinct t.user_id) count
from transactions t
where exists (
  select 1 
  from transactions
  where user_id = t.user_id and date(transaction_date) <> date(t.transaction_date)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c4d56148bf639677c230d2f555a781eb).

Comment: Question is about products?

Comment: @P.Salmon from what I understand it is about dates.